# Entity framework, compare complex types

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do I compare complex types in queries?

Does not work (always returns null, EDIT: since new version of EF it throws exception):
`DbVector3 pos = new DbVector3() { X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0};

db.PhysObjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Position == pos);`

Works:
`DbVector3 pos = new DbVector3() { X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0};

db.PhysObjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Position.X == pos.X && s.Position.Y == pos.Y && s.Position.Z == pos.Z);`

Is there any way to make first example working?

EDIT:
Sorry, I probably mention only in title that this is entity framework.

db is ObjectContext, PhysObjects is ObjectSet<>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not supported, unless both values are in database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the Equals function in your DbVector class, so that when comparisons are made it will be used to compare 2 objects.

```
protected override bool Equals(object comparer)
{
    DbVector3 compareObj = obj as DbVector3;

    return compareObj.X == this.X && compareObj.Y == this.Y && compareObj.Z == this.Z;
}
```

You can also do the same for the == and != operators. Something similar to below :

```
public static bool operator ==(DbVector3 a, DbVector3 b)
{
   return a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y && a.Z == b.Z;
}

public static bool operator !=(DbVector3 a, DbVector3 b)
{
   return !(a == b);
}
```

Have a read of [MSDN - Guidelines for Overriding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, because comparison should be done in database, LINQ query is translated into SQL. I'll test it.

Comment: @Blackfighter It should work if your objects reflect what's in the database properly.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException was unhandled

Message=Unable to create a constant value of type 'SqlTest.DbVector3'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.